# a.out replaced by ELF file format?

Tags: linux, unix, file-format, elf, coredump

I have a few questions:

- Why was `a.out` replaced by `ELF`?
- What were the major flaws in the a.out format that led to the raise of ELF file format?
- Earlier core dumps were based on a.out, but now they are based on ELF. What are the various advantages provided by ELF?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `a.out` format forced shared libraries to occupy a fixed place in memory. If you wanted to distribute an a.out shared library, you had to register its address space. This was good for performance but it didn't scale at all. See for yourself [how tricky it was](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1052) (linuxjournal).

By contrast, in ELF, shared libraries can be loaded anywhere in memory, and can even appear to be at different addresses to different applications running on the same computer (with the code still effectively loaded in only one place in physical memory)! In order to achieve this, in the IA-32 architecture, a register (%ebx) has to be sacrificed. [A more comprehensive reference](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) showing that shared libraries got more complicated in ELF, but that was compiler-side complexity, as opposed to programmer-side.

Comment: A bit of triviality - a.out stood for Assembler OUTput and to this day, gcc will compile C code and defaults to naming the output file a.out, unless another output name is specified, although the output file is still ELF. This was a holdover from the days when code was directly translated to assembler output...nice to see legacy living on in spirit!!

Comment: Notice that although gcc defaults to use the name `a.out`, the format is still ELF.

Comment: I would be both interested in know how ebx was used before and after, and also what coff did differently from elf

Comment: @EvanCarroll The original question does not refer to COFF at all. Your comment sounds like a new question, which I invite you to ask.

Comment: @EvanCarroll In a.out, ebx is available for the user's code as a general-purpose register. In the x86 (32-bit) ELF ABI, ebx holds the address of the Global Offset Table (GOT) so that it is not available for user code. Leaf functions—functions that do not call any other functions—can save it and use it, but unlike a callee-save register, it's not enough to save it on entry to be able to use it in general.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, one of the original problems with a.out format is that it only supported three sections: text, data, and bss. ELF allows any number (or at least many more). The a.out header format was very simple, something like:

```
word <magic>
word <text size>
word <data size>
word <bss size>
```

The ELF format, in contrast, has section headers, with names, sizes, etc.

Having more sections allows for the standard sections, but also gives us const sections, constructor sections, and even one section per function, if we want it.

Comment: This explains the differences, but doesn't explain what's so wrong with a.out or why having more sections is better